# How to implement Twitter API to Bubble.io with Connector API

Tags: api, twitter, bubble.io

Can someone explain how to connect the twitter API Oauth to:

- pull the timeline
- write and post a tweet and a thread
- search tweets

Implement it through Connector API to Bubble.io
Thank you

Pictures for how to authenticate and call api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.